# StackWM tiled manager for windows - How to pin windows to specific areas of the screen

Tags: window-manager, stack

UPD1: The first version of my question was not in English. I'm sorry, the developer of Stack WM placed a link to this site in their app, apparently as a place to get help from the community, so I first thought it was a local help site for the program. My mistake %(

goggle trans
How to pin windows to specific areas of the screen. I bought the application in the store, thanks for the work, except for FancyWM I have not seen anything like this for Windows. Please tell me how to make it so that when using the 4Part scheme, the TotalCommander always appears in the lower right part, and the browser, for example, occupies the entire left part. Thanks in advance for your reply! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please note, this is an English only community. Normally these questions are not answered. Luckily for you, fellow community member Tetsujin was kind enough to add a translation.*

Some programs automatically open in the same spot as they were closed previously, and that setting carries over to the next windows session if windows was shutdown correctly (not a system crash).

Other programs can be forced by holding CTRL while clicking on the close button. This saves a little bit of information into the registry and some programs will then open on that specific location on screen.

A program cannot be in maximized state when it was closed for this to work.

Some programs simply ignore any of these settings and either always spawn in the center of the screen or somewhere in the top left. These cannot be managed by just windows.

There are programs available that allow you to always position a window in a certain spot.

2 programs I know that can do this (both costs money though) are:

- TidyTabs (normally used to group windows together, but per group, you can specify its location and size, and you can create a group of just one app.
- ActualTools Window Manager can restrict placement of a window to a region where you can make it always be that location (user cannot move it away either) or make a region on the screen in which the user (or windows itself) can place the window, making it possible to move and resize the window but it will always be in that region.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, unfortunately I did not specify that it was about the tile window manager Stack WM.